# iOS how to change push notification title when app is running in foreground?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I'm using Urban airship in my app to receive push notifications and all works as expected.
The problem is that when my app is running in foreground and a push received it shows **Notification** as title along with info in payload.But i want to show title as **Notis** instead **Notification** i tried this-

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive )
    {
        NSDictionary* aps = [userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"];
        UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Notis" message:[aps valueForKey:@"alert"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];

    }
    else
    {
         UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        tabBarController.selectedIndex=2;
     [self loadStatisticsInBackground];
       [[UAPush shared] handleNotification:userInfo applicationState:application.applicationState];
    }

    [[UAPush shared] resetBadge];
}
```

But it shows two alerts one that i defined and another is system defined.
Any help would be appreciated.
**Edit:** Ok.. if it is not possible to change title of push notification then Is there any way that we can prevent push alert when app is running in foreground?I don't want to show when my app is running in foreground?

Comment: Is there any way that we can prevent push alert when app is running in foreground?I don't want to show when my app is running in foreground.

Comment: Do you have implementation of the `displayNotificationAlert:` method? (see the [Urban Airship iOS Library 4.0.0
Urban Airship
UAPushNotificationDelegate Protocol Reference](http://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/libraries/ios/latest/Protocols/UAPushNotificationDelegate.html#//api/name/displayNotificationAlert:))

Comment: Do i have to set some delegate to fire this method?

Answer (score 0):

You can just detect if your app is running in foreground and if it does, you don't pass the notification to `UAPush` in -application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:.

Comment: @Blios you changed your code while I was answering this question.

Comment: @Blios when running in foreground, app won't show a push notification, check if there is a same app on your device with a different bundle id. Also set a break point in your application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: and see how the control flow runs.